# Problem sharing proposals from Area51: is the URL really too large?

Tags: bug, status-declined, area-51

I don't know where the problem is (whether is is with area51 share link, or google, or gmail, or my computer), but I am unable to use the "Share This" feature on Area 51 just by using the links. What I get by clicking on "Share This" and then clicking on the mail option (the first one) is this:

[image]

Because of that, if I want to invite people through email (and that is my only option given that I don't have twitter nor facebook and I don't even know what the other options are) I need to copy it and use my email. Not a huge deal, but if the problem is solvable, it might be a good idea to do so.

Comment: What are you using to send mailto links to Gmail?  I enabled it via Gmail notifier (https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10966&query=mailto:&topic=0&type=f&ctx=en:search) and it seems to work fine.  I can only repro that error if I add another 1200 characters to the URL.

Comment: I saw the link, thanks. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I am using a mac, and even though they explain there how to do it for a mac, it doesn't solve the problem... But it was close, and I appreciate the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely the URL is too long for GMail to handle.

The entire body of the e-mail is stuffed into a `mailto:`. Here's what the whole URL looks like for me (over 1200 characters) for the Audio Recording proposal:

> mailto:?subject=Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Audio Recording and Production&body=Hi!%0A%0AI'm supporting a proposal to create a new Q&A website for recording enthusiasts and professionals, audio engineers, producers, music composers and arrangers, to help with microphoning, recording techniques, mixing and mastering, and using the related hard- and software..%0A%0AIt's built on the same software as stackoverflow.com, a hugely popular site where over seven million programmers help each other with difficult programming problems. On Stack Overflow the audience votes for the best answer, so the answer you want is usually right at the top, not on page five.%0A%0AI'm hoping that a site for recording enthusiasts and professionals, audio engineers, producers, music composers and arrangers, to help with microphoning, recording techniques, mixing and mastering, and using the related hard- and software. would have the same kind of network effect and turn into an amazing resource.%0A%0AThe proposal process is going on here:%0A%0Ahttp://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-recording-and-production?referrer=A4RDO_KkyaE1%0A%0AIf you're interested in participating, go to that URL and click on the orange "Follow It!" button.%0A%0AThanks!

As you're doing, the only option is to cut and paste the body into each e-mail you want to send with the given referral link, instead of trying to automate it using the button (which I can confirm works if the e-mail client is Outlook Express).

I would say this is by design.

Comment: A bit silly, huh? But thanks for that. I will leave as unanswered for a couple more days just in case someone else can do something about it or say something else.

Comment: @Vivi: Unfortunately, I think this is an issue with GMail, and not with Area 51, so there's really nothing we can do to fix it except paring down the e-mail body. Maybe you can experiment and find out the maximum URL length it will accept, as that would be useful to know.

Comment: did you see the comment to my question? It very close to a solution.I imagine it is not the place to get this kind of solution, as here we should aim at things that the website can do, but still, maybe someone knows how this can be solved...